The convergence of the Flint Hills series vs the convergence of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^3\sin^2(n)}$
The Flint Hills series, is the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^3\sin^2(n)},$$ and it's an open problem as to whether the series converges. From the proof of Corollary 4 of this paper, it seems that it's also unknown if $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^3\sin^2(n)}$$ converges. Generally speaking (at least when it comes to problems one encounters in a typical calculus/analysis course), given a sequence $(a_n)$ it is easier to check the convergence of $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n,$$ than the convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n.$$
Why then is the problem of determining if the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^3\sin^2(n)}$$ converges a more pressing matter than determining if $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^3\sin^2(n)}$$ converges?

I think you are right. I cannot think of any examples where convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)$ is determined before it is known that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)=0.$

if you read the linked paper you will see that essentially one discusses there the convergence of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^3\sin^2(n)}$ and more generally of similar sequences with various powers  instead of $3,2$; one result is an (almost as there is a border order, $5/2$ for the OP sequence where both convergence and divergence can happen) equivalence between the convergence of the sequence and the irrationality order of $\pi$; from here one can deduce results about the series, but those are weaker in general

Did you notice the $.314$ ?

This is not an answer.
Let $$S_k=\sum_{n=1}^{10^k}\frac{1}{n^3\sin^2(n)}$$ repeating and continuing the calculations
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & S_k \\
 0 & 1.412282927 \\
 1 & 3.538718152 \\
 2 & 4.805693682 \\
 3 & 30.17479017 \\
 4 & 30.31451083 \\
 5 & 30.31452087 \\
 6 & 30.31453940 \\
 7 & 30.31454593 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

I don't understand why this is interesting. Can you please explain?

@Hilbert. I never claimed that it was. I just produced more numbers. Cheers
